# Hit Test WPF 3D Model parts

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-controls, 3d, hittest

I have a big `ModelVisual3D` (e.g. car) which is divided into many smaller `GeometryModel3D` objects (e.g. tyres, seats, wheels, etc.).

I would like to hit test the `ModelVisual3D` when the mouse is clicked and determine which `GeometryModel3D` was hit. I can hit test my car (the `ModelVisual3D`) but cannot determine which part of the car (the `GeometryModel3D` objects) was clicked.

Does anybody have an idea how I can determine the exact part of my model when handling a `MouseLeftButtonDown` event (or any other Mouse event)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at http://www.kindohm.com/technical/ComplexVisuals.htm - I believe the mechanisms explained there will help.

Comment: Link not Working!

Answer (score 0):

This blog post shows how to do ray testing with the framework:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/wpf3d/archive/2009/05/18/3d-hit-testing.aspx

The result in the callback has detail on the intersected mesh from which you can get the specific part of the mesh which was intersected.